# Replace text in word doc including headers, textbox etc. using late binding

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, binding

I'm using VBA from excel to open a doc and replace text at certain tags that I'm setting.  The problem is it only seems to work for the mainbody, not the header or textboxes that I have.  I'm following several exambles especially [this on here.](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?48071-Find-and-replace-in-word-doc-from-excel-vba). They say the main goal is to use a Word.range object and "for each" loop through all range object, which will include the header, etc.  Unfortunately that's not working.  All instances of <> are changed in the main body, but not the header or anywhere else. Also, there's the caveat that I have to use late binding so I can move this to other versions of Excel and Word.  So what am I doing wrong?

```
Sub editWordDocTEst()
Dim wdApp, wdDoc As Object
Dim docRange As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "testdoc.docx")
'Set docRange = wdDoc.Range
wdApp.Visible = True
wdApp.Activate

For Each docRange In wdDoc.StoryRanges

With wdDoc.content.Find
    .Text = "<<testText>>"
    .Replacement.Text = "TheNewText"
    .Execute Replace:=2

End With

Next docRange


End Sub
```

Comment: Here's a good overview: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Comment: Use early binding until you got your code to work. Then change the declarations before publishing. As far as I know the Headers/Footers are separate from the document body and there is no single range to includes both worlds.

Comment: you’re iterating docRange, but not using the docRange’s Find object

Comment: If you bookmarked the ranges (e.g. bookmark <<testText>> as testText), you could simply overwrite the bookmarked ranges without worrying what part of the document they're in. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170358/vba-word-filling-out-multiple-forms-with-pop-up-window/61170917#61170917

Comment: «Here's a good overview: wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm» What that article omits to say, though, is that the StoryRanges object is buggy where Find/Replace is concerned; it does not work on headers & footers in more than the first Section of a document. For that, you need code like: https://www.msofficeforums.com/90012-post4.html

Comment: @"slightly snarky" Thanks.  I fixed the object I was iterating to docRange but still having some problems.  The other comments are addressing that.

Comment: @Variatus " I started using early bindings, but I was getting a "Library not registered" error I was unable to fix using the MS Word 14.0 library with Word 2010, which I was unable to fix.  So I switched to late bindings.

Comment: Well, the difference between early and late binding is that in late binding VBA selects the library when it's needed. If it doesn't exist VBA won't be able to select it.

Comment: «I was getting a "Library not registered" error I was unable to fix using the MS Word 14.0 library with Word 2010» To avoid that, compile your VBA project on the earliest Word version you'll be supporting.